# It is common for a recruiter to call your current employer to ask for reference?

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, human-resources, references

I've a friend who finished a long round of interviews and passed all the technical tests. During the last meeting he has been asked by an HR manager if he could talk with his **current** boss to get some reference.

It is a common behaviour? What I should do if I would face the same situation??

Comment: Ask for a offer in writing before they can call. You don't want to risk your current job for a job that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Hi, you can look at these answer: https://www.quora.com/Do-new-potential-employers-have-the-right-to-call-your-present-employer-for-reference

Comment: I've never heard of anyone asking for references before offering the job, personally.

Comment: I think that a reference should be used to decide if the candidate could be a good fit. Am I wrong about that?